# catkin_tools and qtcreator

Tags: ros, qtcreator, catkin-tools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am using `catkin_tools` and I have configured QTCreator as told in the [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#catkin_tools-1), more concretely following [these instructions](http://www.rag.com.ve/developing-in-ros-indigo-using-qtcreator/).

However, I find myself manually opening each package as a project and I am working with tons of packages. Although CTRL+Click works (it takes me to other packages), I find a bit annoying that I have to open each package manually.

Is there a better solution for this (something like we did with `catkin_make`)?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220345/catkin_tools-and-qtcreator/) by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1305 on 2015-11-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I agree that this can be somewhat tedious, but as building with `catkin_tools` means performing isolated builds, i.e. every package is it's own CMake project, I don't think there's a easy solution for this. QtCreator per default just opens CMake projects. With `catkin_tools` there are many of those as opposed to a single one (as when using `catkin_make`).

I suppose it could be possible to write some sort of script that adds and opens all packages in a workspace with QtCreator either by using command line options or generating a appopriate config file, but I'm not aware of existing efforts.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3